# I just cloned meanjs project but there is no app folder why?

Tags: meanjs

Hello I just cloned meanjs project and somehow there is no app folder under that project. Why they changed the structure? Am I doing something wrong? Sorry just try to learn Node and one of those tutorials I follow up is using that project

[Meanjs project github link](https://github.com/meanjs/mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the new version 0.4.0 has been already merged to the master branch and it has a new folder structure, if you want to work with the version 0.3.x that has the folder structure you mentioned you can clone the latest tagged 0.3.3 release:

```
git clone --branch v0.3.3 https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git
```

This will checkout to a 'detached HEAD' branch that has the 0.3.3(current latest 0.3.x) version and the folder structure you're looking for.

After cloning this version you can use the [yeoman generator](http://meanjs.org/generator.html) to create your template project from there.

Comment: Is there any guides telling what is where in that new structure? All the tutorials describe the old structure with app folder, and its confusing. There is directory `modules`, some of it structure is same with app, some are not. I don't want to use the old structure either.

Comment: Hi @proxy , yes I agree, all tutorials I could find point to the old structure. I had the same hard time to find out by myself how it's currently structured in new 4.x versions. I guess that's why they're asking for help on documenting it in their project site: http://meanjs.org/docs/0.4.x/

Comment: I cloned by ``git clone --branch v0.3.3 https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git`` but I can't have app folder , just modules folder with client , server , test inside

Answer (score 1):

> The app folder is removed, which is the major concern for the noobs trying their hands on MEANjs following the older tutorials. **Controllers,views, models are now moved into a separate folder called *modules* which was previously in the public folder**. You can explore modules/core/server and modules/user/server of your project

for future people running into this same problem.

credits goes to [pooja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6508541/pooja-malvi)'s answer at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506913/yo-meanjs-not-creating-app-folder?answertab=votes#tab-top)