# yo meanjs not creating app folder

Tags: node.js, npm, meanjs, yo

I am a beginner to mean.

I have followed the following steps to create meanjs app :

1. installed node v0.12.7
2. npm install -g bower
3. npm install -g grunt-cli
4. npm install -g yo
5. npm install -g generator-meanjs
6. cd C:\Users\SHIVAM\Desktop\MyApp
7. yo meanjs

[MyApp folder containing mean directory created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMmYP.png)

[Error occured on yo meanjs 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zQ2b.png)

Please provide a solution . I am struck at the first phase. I need to get started as sson as possible .

Comment: have you tried with sudo ?

Comment: i am working on windows powershell

Answer (score 4):

Version 0.4.* has different folder structure. The tutorial you are following is probably using earlier version of meanjs. You can find the new structure here-http://www.bossable.com/954/version-0-4-0/ She has compared the structure with the older one. I was going through the same problem. Follow these tutorials, it will be of great help.

The following directories have been changed in the 0.4.* versions of Meanjs; 0.4.2 is still unstable. 0.4.0 and 0.4.1 is recommended for beginners to get on MEAN.

-New files have been added

1) **gulpfile.js**-Gulp is relatively faster than grunt because gulp focuses on code rather than cofiguration. It uses node.js’ streams, and executes faster, since it does not open/close files, or create intermediary copies all the time. The lack of any up-front configuration, especially, specifying a source and destination is noticed immediately in this file.
2) **protractor.conf.js**-Support file for end-to-end testing in angularjs applications. (Pretty Neat.)

The app folder is removed, which is the major concern for the noobs trying their hands on MEANjs following the older tutorials. Controllers,views, models are now moved into a separate folder called **modules** which was previously in the **public** folder.
You can explore modules/core/server and modules/user/server of your project

Addition of **client**, **server** and **test** in `modules/core` and `modules/user` folder. All the client side angular will now be in the `modules/core/client` making it easier to access all services and directives of different modules of the application at one place. And all the backend or server-side files goes to `modules/core/server`.

`public/application.js` and `public/config.js` are now config.js and init.js in `modules/core/client/app` folder.

**config** folder is split and new folders **assets** and **lib** are added.
The previous env folder have been split into **env** and **assets**. All the references, mongodb port, session keys goes to the environment(env) whereas new libraries we are defining into our project goes to assets. For instance new css, sass or less reference will be defined into `asset/default.js`. **config.js** and **init.js** are merged into one file `config/config.js`.
**lib** contains express.js, mongoose.js and socket.io.js.

**node_modules** is pretty much exactly the same as the previous versions of meanjs. 
These are the major changes in the folder structure. New models and controllers are added into the `modules/users/server` according to your application, just so you don't get lost while developing your project.

Comment: This answer would be very good if you elaborated on some of the details in that link. It's much easier to read information already here than to follow a link, as you have to wait for another page load, etc.